# FART replace mulitple extensions

Tags: cmd.exe

Is it possible to use FART for replace multiple extensions in 1 go?

I already tried it with -f, but that goes only for 1 replace.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use

```
rename *.old *.new
```

I've no idea what 'Fart' is.

Comment: I use that now, "ren *.old *.new". But i wanted to know if fart.exe also would work.

Comment: what is fart.exe? and why look to use something else when ren/rename does what you want?

Comment: https://emtunc.org/blog/03/2011/farting-the-easy-way-find-and-replace-text/ I want to use a exe to use it in a batch

Comment: And if i search on questions about fart.exe, in google, i get a lot of hits on this site. So i know there are people who are using Fart.

Comment: Sounds like you need to reach out to the dev